# TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable error message

Tags: python, dataframe

```
liste_products = df_cleaned['Description'].unique()

X = pd.DataFrame()
for key, occurence in list_products:
    X.loc[:, key] = list(map(lambda x:int(key.upper() in x), liste_products))
```

THROWS ERROR

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-181-6d04c94ad6e2> in <module>
       X = pd.DataFrame()
       for key, occurence in list_products:
---->      X.loc[:, key] = list(map(lambda x:int(key.upper() in x), liste_products))

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Comment: What is `liste_products`? Note that you have `list_products` rather than `liste_products` in your for loop (the difference of an e on the end of list).

Comment: type(list_products) = list

type(liste_products) = numpy.ndarray

both are different

Comment: What is the type of ``list``, ``map`` and ``int`` in your code? One of these names was used to store a ``DataFrame``.

Comment: It worked !!! 
I once used list as a variable to store dataframe and forgot to delete.